# Importing existing CDK Project, Getting issue while performing cdk ls command

Tags: python, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I've cloned an existing CDK Project, to use it for further development. I was able to install all the python dependencies as well as cdk/npm dependencies using:

> python -m pip install lambda/requirements.txt
>
> npm install

After the installation, I've tried performing the cdk ls command but I'm getting below mentioned error:

```
D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac>npm run cdk synth
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> ent-sls-add-api@0.1.0 cdk
> cdk "synth"

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

    D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:52



resp.error = util.error(new Error(), error);
                          ^
ParameterNotFound:
    at Request.extractError (D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners D:\Users\xyz\.aws\Work\Project\iac\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)

Subprocess exited with error 1
```

I've deleted the node_modules folder and tried re-installing the libraries, but I still get the same error.
The project uses codepipeline as well, could it be an issue because of that. I've just started working with AWS CDK therefore I'm not sure about this issue. If anyone has seen this error before, please point me into the right direction. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your project references some SSM parameter. I found this error:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ssm/modules/parameternotfound.html

Make sure you are authorized to right AWS account/region. Look for parameters reference in code.

Comment: Thank you, the project uses SSM parameters but the new account doesn't have these configured. I'll be configuring them and try again.